# Melhor maneira de excluir um sample de um DataFrame ao mesmo tempo o guardo em uma variável

Tags: python, aprendizagem-de-máquina, aprendizado-supervisionado

Olá, estou começando em aprendizado supervisionado e quero separar um **sample** aleatório do meu dataframe para teste deixando o resto para o treinamento.

Eu consegui o resultado que esperava, mas estou incerto se não esta mais para uma gambiarra.

Assim, se alguém mais experiente puder dar uma olhada e me mostrar uma maneira mais confiável, ficaria grato.

Ficou assim meu código

```
import pandas as pd 

uri = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guilhermesilveira/2d2efa37d66b6c84a722ea627a897ced/raw/10968b997d885cbded1c92938c7a9912ba41c615/tracking.csv'

dados = pd.read_csv(uri)

teste = dados.sample(24)
treino = dados[~dados.isin(teste)].dropna()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, na blibioteca "sklearn" você pode importar uma função própria para separação de dados entre treino e teste, e ainda escolher o tamanho da razão treino/teste:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3)
```

Sendo X o que será usado para predizer, Y o que será predito e 'test_size' o valor da porcentagem de dados designado a teste.

Vale ressaltar que é importante seguir essa ordem de (X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test) nessa função para garantir o funcionamento correto.

Comment: Exatamente isto que eu estava procurando. Muito obrigado!